# horizontal scroll bar in android phonegap mobile application

Tags: android, html, cordova, horizontalscrollview

Horizontal scrolling is not working in `HTML5` `phonegap` and `Android` mobile application.

please provide some solution using `css3`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) and its latest version [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)